with dataclass objects Python code runs slower
I need to speed up my python code for my pHd project. I am trying functions with different parameters. Since I got lots of variables that I calculate in the code, I created 4 classes from @dataclass with several attributes. If I use dataclass derived object as an input, function returns slower. I tried to speed up with numba but certain types are not supported. I may use a dictionary inside a function but not sure if jit supports it, I haven't tried it yet.
I have lots of variables in the code, so I need to group them for readability and management.
Any ideas?
import time
#import torch
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib as plt
from numba import njit, jit, int32, float32, types
from numba.experimental import jitclass

from typing import Tuple
import cython
from dataclasses import dataclass
from functools import partial


@dataclass()
class Kpi():
    name: str
    value1: int
    value2: float

spec = [
    ('name', types.unicode_type),
    ('value1', float32),
    ('value2', int32)
]

@jitclass(spec)
class Kpi_jit:
    def __init__(self, name, value1, value2):
        self.name = name
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2


def calc_raw_1(x1, x2, stext=None):
    if stext == 'AS':
        return (x1*x2)+(x1*x2), x1+x2+x1+x2
    else:
        return (x1 * x2) * 2 + (x1 * x2), (x1 + x2 + x1 + x2) * 2

@njit
def calc_accel_1(x1, x2, stext=None):
    if stext == 'AS':
        return (x1 * x2) + (x1 * x2), x1 + x2 + x1 + x2
    else:
        return (x1 * x2) * 2 + (x1 * x2), (x1 + x2 + x1 + x2) * 2

def calc_raw_2(x1:float, x2:float, stext:str=None):
    if stext == 'AS':
        return (x1 * x2) + (x1 * x2), x1 + x2 + x1 + x2
    else:
        return (x1 * x2) * 2 + (x1 * x2), (x1 + x2 + x1 + x2) * 2

@njit
def calc_accel_2(x1:float, x2:float, stext:str=None):
    if stext == 'AS':
        return (x1 * x2) + (x1 * x2), x1 + x2 + x1 + x2
    else:
        return (x1 * x2) * 2 + (x1 * x2), (x1 + x2 + x1 + x2) * 2

def calc_raw_3(x1:float, x2:float, stext:str=None) ->Tuple[float, float]:
    if stext == 'AS':
        return (x1 * x2) + (x1 * x2), x1 + x2 + x1 + x2
    else:
        return (x1 * x2) * 2 + (x1 * x2), (x1 + x2 + x1 + x2) * 2
@jit(nopython=True)
def calc_accel_3(x1:float, x2:float, stext:str=None) ->Tuple[float, float]:
    if stext == 'AS':
        return (x1 * x2) + (x1 * x2), x1 + x2 + x1 + x2
    else:
        return (x1 * x2) * 2 + (x1 * x2), (x1 + x2 + x1 + x2) * 2


@jit(nopython=True)
def calc_accel_4(kpi:Kpi) ->Tuple[float, float]:
    if kpi.name == 'AS':
        return (kpi.value1 * kpi.value2) + (kpi.value1 * kpi.value2), kpi.value1 + kpi.value2 + kpi.value1 + kpi.value2
    else:
        return (kpi.value1 * kpi.value2) * 2 + (kpi.value1 * kpi.value2), (kpi.value1 + kpi.value2 + kpi.value1 + kpi.value2) * 2

@jit(nopython=True)
def calc_accel_5(x1:float, x2:float, stext:str=None) ->Tuple[float, float]:
    if stext == 'AS':
        return (x1 * x2) + (x1 * x2), x1 + x2 + x1 + x2
    else:
        return (x1 * x2) * 2 + (x1 * x2), (x1 + x2 + x1 + x2) * 2




x1 = 5.2
x2 = 989
filter_text = 'AB'

#kpi = Kpi()
kpi = Kpi(name = filter_text, value1 = x1, value2 = x2)
kpi_jit = Kpi_jit(name = filter_text, value1 = x1, value2 = x2)


#temp1, temp2 = calc_accel_1(x1, x2, s)
#temp1, temp2 = calc_accel_2(x1, x2, s)
#temp1, temp2 = calc_accel_3(x1, x2, s)

print("====================================================")

s = time.time()
for i in range(10000000):
    if filter_text == 'AS':
        temp1 = (x1*x2)+(x1*x2)
        temp2 = x1+x2+x1+x2
    else:
        temp1 = (x1 * x2)*2 + (x1 * x2)
        temp2 = (x1 + x2 + x1 + x2) *2
print(f"calc in fnc : {round(time.time()- s, 2)} sec.")

s = time.time()
for i in range(10000000):
    temp1, temp2 = calc_raw_1(x1, x2, filter_text)
print(f"calc_raw_1  : {round(time.time()- s, 2)} sec.")

s = time.time()
for i in range(10000000):
    temp1, temp2 = calc_accel_1(x1, x2, filter_text)
    #
print(f"calc_accel_1: {round(time.time()- s, 2)} sec.")

"""s = time.time()
for i in range(10000000):
    temp1, temp2 = calc_raw_2(x1, x2, s)
    #
print(f"calc_raw_2  : {round(time.time()- s, 2)} sec.")
"""
s = time.time()
for i in range(10000000):
    temp1, temp2 = calc_accel_2(x1, x2, filter_text)
    #
print(f"calc_accel_2: {round(time.time()- s, 2)} sec.")

"""
s = time.time()
for i in range(10000000):
    temp1, temp2 = calc_raw_3(x1, x2, s)
    #
print(f"calc_raw_3  : {round(time.time()- s, 2)} sec.")
"""
s = time.time()
for i in range(10000000):
    temp1, temp2 = calc_accel_3(x1, x2, filter_text)
    #
print(f"calc_accel_3: {round(time.time()- s, 2)} sec.")


s = time.time()
for i in range(10000000):
    temp1, temp2 = calc_accel_4(kpi_jit)
    #
print(f"calc_accel_4: {round(time.time()- s, 2)} sec.")

s = time.time()
for i in range(10000000):
    temp1, temp2 = calc_accel_5(kpi.value1, kpi.value2, kpi.name)
    #
print(f"calc_accel_5: {round(time.time()- s, 2)} sec.")

calc in fnc : 3.07 sec.
calc_accel_1: 2.56 sec.
calc_accel_2: 2.59 sec.
calc_accel_3: 2.62 sec.
calc_accel_4: 5.31 sec.
calc_accel_5: 3.19 sec.


The variable s is used in two different contexts, causing a naming conflict. Since fixing this will have a big impact on the results, please re-run your code and update your question if the results are still not sufficient for you.

Also, you should not frequently access global variables in benchmarks. Accessing global variables is slow, so a candidate with more frequent access may appear slower than it actually is.

if you think dictionary will work faster then first check it and later ask question.

maybe you should reduced number of multiplications temp1 = (x1*x2)+(x1*x2) convert to a = (x1*x2) ; temp1 = a+a. And temp1 = (x1 * x2)*2 + (x1 * x2) to temp1 = a + a + a

Thanks Ken. This calculations are just examples. I really did not noticed the confusion. I updated the code and the results. Still If I use dataclass object as input, all the saving in jit compilation seems to dissapear.

@furas, original code have more calculations within various functions. I just wanted to see the gains of numba. as number of calculations increase, function with jit runs faster. But it diminishes if ı use dataclass objects as inputs.

On my PC (both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22), calc_accel_4 is the fastest of those jit functions. BTW, your execution results do not include calc_raw_1. Are you actually executing a different code? Also, your execution environment includes dependencies that are irrelevant to the problem, such as cython. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

After several trials, I ignored calc_raw_X functions since they are similar in performance. in my last trials I am focused on functions using Numba

Numba is best in replacing python loops, not so good to replace some stuff inside a loop. Second thing, numba works best on primitives and numpy arrays of primitives, not on some arbitrary python objects (e.g. dataclass). You may want to change programming language or entire architecture of your code.
